# How to pass a variable to templates for multiple controllers in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, templates, controllers

How to specify a group of controllers (e.g. all controllers for an admin section) and assign a variable or a service that would be accessible in all templates rendered by those controllers?

An equivalent in Laravel would be specifying different middleware for different route groups.

I'm NOT looking for these answers:

1. Global Variables - the variable/service would be unnecessarily injected  to some of the controllers (e.g. front-end controllers.)
2. Embedding other controllers in templates - a workaround that is slow, verbose and repetitive.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Symfony controllers generally return the response version of a template so there is no space for middleware. Generally when a Symfony controller returns a response it is a completely parsed string. If you want to be able to handle it after the controller you would need to return a set of parameters with something to identify the template and then set up a `Kernel::Response` listener to handle extra parameters and the actual creation of the response object.

Comment: Two options I can think of, and you've basically said both of them

1) Service - have a function to get the variable if the user has permission, or the request is to the right url/controller etc

2) Middleware - use event listeners to set the variable on the right requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify controllers that you would like to pass an extra param, let's make its implements some interface like AdminInterface.Then to pass params to view, there are several ways:

1/listener to kernel.view :

```
public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $result = $event->getControllerResult();

        if (!$result instanceof AdminInterface || !isset($result['template']) || !isset($result['data'])) {
            return;
        }

        $data = array_merge($result['data'], array('myvar' => 'value'));
        $rendered = $this->templating->render($result['template'], $data);

        $event->setResponse(new Response($rendered));
    }
```

2/pass an attribute a request that contains your params and get it in your controller by $request->attributes->get('myVar') and pass it directly to template.

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();
    if (!$result instanceof AdminInterface) {
       return;
    }
    $event->getRequest->attributes->set('myvar', 'value');
}
```

for more details for symfony kernel events look at [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html).
Hope help you.